# UIImage imageWithData timeout reliability

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I'm downloading an image from my server

```
    dispatch_async(BG_QUEUE, ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

        if (image)
        {
            [self cacheImage:image];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self imageIsCached];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self imageFetchDidFail];
            });
        }
    });
```

This does time out... but my question is, is this reliable? I've seen people talk about NSURLConnection to download images from the web, but all the implementations look heavy handed for what I want... Is there something else as neat and concise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It's a third party networking client written in Objective-C, and amongst other things it includes are some categories on certain UIKit classes, [including UIImageView](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html). This is pretty encapsulated and widely used, and is probably as *neat and concise* a solution as you'll be able to find.